# Mysql Sum data from Multiple Dimension

Tags: mysql, sql

I've encountered a problem where I need to sum data based on multiple dimension, the source data look like this:

[image: ![enter image description here]

The goal is to create a result like:

```
> Bank_name   total_issuer_fee   total_acq_fee   total_biller_fee   total_sw_fee
  BRI         xxx                xxx             xxx                xxx
  BNI         xxx                xxx             xxx                xxx
  MDR         xxx                xxx             xxx                xxx
  BTN         xxx                xxx             xxx                xxx
```

Here is my code to produce data in the image above:

```
select
issuer, acquirer, biller,
sum(total_issuer_fee) as total_issuer_fee,
sum(total_acq_fee) as total_acq_fee,
sum(total_biller_fee) as total_biller_fee,
sum(total_sw_fee) as total_sw_fee
from <source_table>
group by issuer, acquirer, biller;
```

appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: what is issue?? you should group by only with issuer

Comment: You want to group by 3 fields, but what's the problem you have encountered?

Comment: your expected output has 5 columns, but in your query you take 7 columns?

Comment: thanks for the response, i want to group total fees contributed by each bank, lets say i want to know how much BRI contributed to total fees from BRI as issuer/acquirer/biller

Answer (score 0):

You may try this, I am assuming `Bank_name` in your expected output is `issuer` from the query. So you don't need another columns in your final output.

```
select
biller as Bank_name,
sum(total_issuer_fee) as total_issuer_fee,
sum(total_acq_fee) as total_acq_fee,
sum(total_biller_fee) as total_biller_fee,
sum(total_sw_fee) as total_sw_fee
from <source_table>
group by  biller;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to *overcount* the values -- that is, count each row three times once for `acquirer`, `issuer`, and `biller`, then you can use `union all`:

```
select bank,
       sum(total_issuer_fee) as total_issuer_fee,
       sum(total_acq_fee) as total_acq_fee,
       sum(total_biller_fee) as total_biller_fee,
       sum(total_sw_fee) as total_sw_fee
from ((select issuer as bank_name, t.*
       from t
      ) union all
      (select acquirer as bank_name, t.*
       from t
      ) union all
      (select biller as bank_name, t.*
       from t
      )
     ) b     
group by bank;
```

Comment: if there is some record that shares the same value (like issuer=acquirer), is this query produce duplicate data?

Comment: @galih . . . That seems consistent with your description.  You can filter out those cases, of course, so they are only counted once.